# inserting a range of struct vector into a vector of a struct member type

Tags: boost, vector, struct, c++03

Is it possible to insert range of struct directly into vector of the same type (same type of a member of struct).

Let's have a struct and vectors like this:

```
struct pnt {
  char _name;
  int _type;
  bool _aux;
  };

std::vector<pnt> pnts;
std::vector<int> pntType;
```

The question is that how to insert a range of **pnts** into **pntType** using single standard line of C++98:

```
void insert (iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

or even Boost library.
Since I am using this often in different parts of my code, I am trying to avoid doing this in a loop. The last option is defining a function for that.

**EDIT**:

I know the insert syntax. What I cannot do is how to insert from **pnts** (only _type of each member) into **pntType**

Comment: exactly.......Please see the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using boost range:

```
boost::copy(pnts | transformed(std::mem_fn(&pnt::_type)), std::back_inserter(pntType));
```

Or even

```
boost::copy_range<std::vector<int>>(pnts | transformed(std::mem_fn(&pnt::_type)));
```

See it **<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c565c41a1045b669)</kbd>**

Note you can use `boost::bind(&pnt:_type,_1)` instead of `mem_fn` to allow for your compiler version

**Updated** To show with specific first/last iterators, and compiling in c++03 mode:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aac8a120ba964222)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace boost::adaptors;
using namespace boost;

struct pnt {
    char _name;
    int _type;
    bool _aux;
};

int main() {

    std::vector<pnt> pnts(6);
    std::vector<int> pntType;

    boost::copy(
            make_iterator_range(pnts.begin(), pnts.begin()+3) | transformed(bind(&pnt::_type, _1)), 
            std::back_inserter(pntType));
}
```

Comment: nice idea as well, but 'auto' needs higher C++ standard.

Comment: Then don't use auto? I've updated the sample (honestly, I think std::mem_fn is c++11 too, but I didn't see a [tag:c++03])

Comment: using boost copying all the member. isn't it?

Comment: Yes. I was making examples. You can provide any range, of course (`boost::make_iterator_range(f,l) | transformed(...)` works)

Comment: You're a bit slow :) I mentioned this in my first reply. Anyways. You can still levare boost range to save on the repetitive typing for `boost::make_transform_iterator`, was my point.

Comment: sorry, I didn't see the update....I'd like to use higher standard, if I was allowed.

Comment: Again, that's not the point of my answer. You can replace std::mem_fn with boost::bind, and auto with explicit types. Still you have the benefit of requiring the transformation function only once. I've updated my answer to make it a little bit more clear

Comment: how to update this [Live on Coliru][1] for range from v1.begin(), v1.begin()+3        [1]: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Comment: @H'H As in my omment 55 minutes ago: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aac8a120ba964222)** (also updating my answer)

Comment: @H'H @sehe There seems to be a [`boost::mem_fn`](http://www.boost.org/libs/bind/mem_fn.html) that I think should be usable in c++03.

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: There is a better way than my first suggestion (see bottom), since we're already using Boost. The problem with std::transform and std::insert_iterator is that v2 is resized several times, which is wasteful considering that we know the width of the range in advance. Using boost::transform_iterator and boost::bind, it is possible to avoid the problem like this:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

struct A {
  int x;
};

int main() {
  A arr[] = {
    { 0 }, { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 }, { 4 }, { 5 }, { 6 }
  };

  std::vector<A> v1(arr, arr + 6);
  std::vector<int> v2;

  v2.insert(v2.begin(),
            boost::make_transform_iterator(v1.begin() + 2, boost::bind(&A::x, _1)),
            boost::make_transform_iterator(v1.begin() + 4, boost::bind(&A::x, _1)));

  std::copy(v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

OLD SUGGESTION:

boost::bind works with data member pointers, so using C++98 and Boost, you could do something like this without changing your struct:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

struct A {
  int x;
};

int main() {
  A arr[] = {
    { 0 }, { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 }, { 4 }, { 5 }, { 6 }
  };

  std::vector<A> v1(arr, arr + 6);
  std::vector<int> v2;

  // one-liner here:
  std::transform(v1.begin() + 2,
                 v1.begin() + 4,
                 std::insert_iterator<std::vector<int> >(v2, v2.begin()),
                 boost::bind(&A::x, _1));

  std::copy(v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: no need for boost bind, AFAICT. `std::mem_fn` does the same (with less code)

Comment: `std::mem_fn` is not C++98, though.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting one container into the other works like this:

```
pntType.insert(pntType.begin(),pnts.begin(),pnts.end());
```

To be able to insert the correct type, you should add a conversion operator to `int` to your struct.

```
struct pnt {
  char _name;
  int _type;
  bool _aux;

  operator int (){
    return _type;
  }     
};
```

Comment: although this works, implicit type conversion from `pnt` to a type like `int` seems a really bad idea.